# Add column to table in C# & Entity Framework code-first without deleting DB content

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database with several tables in AZURE SQL Server.

I want to add a new column to one of the tables, but I want to keep all the content of the tables including the table with the new column; hence I don't want to use the

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDbContext>());
```

My code looks like this:

```
public class DBTables : DbContext
{
    public DBTables() : base(ProductKeys.GetDbKey()) 
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ElementsForPointTable> ElementsForPointTable { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StationsDetailsTable> StationsDetailsTable { get; set; }
}
```

How do I do it?

Comment: What's the issue with normal Add-Migration and Update-Database through package console?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) to update the database scheme.

1. Open **Package Manager Console** (Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console)
2. Run **Enable-Migrations** command
3. Change your model
4. Run **Add-Migration** command in Package Manager Console.
5. Run **Update-Database** command to apply your model changes to the database.

Comment: But i am connecting  the db name dynamically so how does the migration tools knows to what db to migrate to ? I have attached my code sample above

Comment: By your connection string in your Web.config

Comment: Suppose bullet number 2 should be **Enable-Migrations** (with an s)